# Flutter google_maps_places dont show places after search

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, google-places-api

I tried use google maps places to get lat/lng after searching to a places, with help the autoComplete function.

How can i solve this problem?

[image: Problem_picture]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';


// Google Api Key
const kGoogleApiKey = "....";

// to get places detail (lat/lng)
GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class PlaceSearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color primaryColor, primaryColorAccent;

  PlaceSearchPage({Key key, this.primaryColor, this.primaryColorAccent})
      : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onSubmitted: (s) async {
                Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                    context: context,
                    apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                    mode: Mode.overlay, // Mode.fullscreen
                    language: "de",
                    components: [new Component(Component.country, "de"), new Component(Component.country, "en")]);
```

Comment: The view is either behind the other views.  Normally this happens when you add a control to the wrong control

Comment: what do you main exactly? can you please add a axample for your resolve

Comment: A view has layers.  There is a Top View (what is visible) and a Back View (behind another View).  So when you add a new item to a view it must be on Top to be seen.

Comment: Is did works for one time then not more :(. [a new Picture](https://i.ibb.co/7zPkTCp/Screenshot-1565496344.png)

Comment: What did you change?  Are you getting a valid response?  Are you waiting to get the entire response before displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem :`( the error log => "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found that i got message "no billing account is setted..."